# Ubuntu 20.04 login prompt not showing after boot -- welcome page is shown instead

Tags: boot, login

My Ubuntu 20.04 installation behaves rather oddly -- sometimes after booting, the login prompt is not shown. What is shown instead is the "Welcome" page that has subsequent prompts similar to the installation sequence (i.e. having to choose the default language, the keyboard, the timezone, etc) and then hangs.
Has anyone else encountered this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Your installation DVD or USB still in the drive?

Comment: The program responsible for displaying these prompts is ```/usr/libexec/gnome-initial-setup```. It must get called somehow at session startup. Check if by any chance you have it in your "Startup programs".

Comment: @vanadium no, this happens when booting using the drive that the OS was installed on. This happens irregularly, about a third of the time...